# Vuser distribution along generators

Tags: loadrunner, load-generator

I have 6 *VUsers* on 2 *Load generators*.
With *Percentage scenario mode* Controller distributes them like this:

```
VUser ID | Load Generator
---------|---------------
1        |  vm-1
2        |  vm-1
3        |  vm-1
4        |  vm-2
5        |  vm-2
6        |  vm-2
```

I would like distribution with alternating (repeating sequence) Load Generators like this:

```
VUser ID | Load Generator
---------|---------------
1        |  vm-1
2        |  vm-2
3        |  vm-1
4        |  vm-2
5        |  vm-1
6        |  vm-2
```

How can I achieve this?
Changing to *Group mode* gives me option to specify generator manually, but this is inconvenient and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Create two groups of three apiece and ramp them up at the same time.  Assign each group to a distinct generator

Comment: With this scenario I have to crate each group for each generator? And if I have 5 tests with 5 generators I have to create 25 groups. Is there any quicker way?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do similar thing for 1500+ VU and what worked best for me was to copy all the generators (distinct one's) in order in one script by double clicking on it in *Run* tab. So let's say you have 10 so copy 10 rows in "Load Generators" column after assigning each row with unique generators. For me there were 9

```
'loadgen00'
'loadgen01'
'loadgen02'
.
.
.
.
.
'loadgen08'.
```

Once you have done this, you can then start pasting it for below series and it will take generators in same order. You will get a message "The dimensions of the data on the clipboard is larger than the selected region. Truncate clipboard data?", just click NO. Not sure if this helps but earlier I was changing for each of the 1500+ VU's manually and it was painful and time taking. By this I save lot of time.